# Choose Specific Date Range on X-axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that shows my total_Sales, Total_cost & Total_profit over a period of time. My graph only plots the dates on which changes occur in my dataframe. I'm wondering if I can change that to show monthly data from the first transaction to today.

```
Date        Ticker  Total_Sales   Total_Cost    Profit
01/11/22    CELH    2000.00            0.0      2000.00
07/20/22    MMMB    2040.00            0.0      2040.00
07/28/22    MMMB    2080.00            0.0      2080.00
08/26/22    MMMB    2120.00           21.0      2099.00
09/13/22    AAPL    3920.00          721.0      3199.00
09/13/22    AAPL    5120.00          721.0      4399.00
09/27/22    AAPL    7820.00          721.0      7099.00
10/20/22    MMMB    7860.00          721.0      7139.00
11/01/22    MMMB    7900.00          721.0      7179.00
11/09/22    AAPL    8540.00          833.0      7707.00
11/14/22    AAPL    8540.07          833.0      7707.07
11/14/22    AAPL    8540.14          833.0      7707.14
11/14/22    AAPL    8540.21          833.0      7707.21
11/14/22    CELH    18540.21        1283.0      17257.21
11/15/22    AAPL    18620.21        1483.0      17137.21
11/16/22    AAPL    18920.21        2303.0      16617.21
```

*For clarification: The Total_Sales, Total_Cost & Profit are cumulative. So it's the total sales, cost & profit of a portfolio not of an individual stock transaction.

The graph that I'm getting from plotting this data by using the following code:

> plt2.plot(x = 'Date', y=['Total_Sales', 'Total_Cost', 'Profit'], kind='line', linewidth=4)
> plt.show()

Where plt2 is my pd.DataFrame that holds the data shown in the table above.
[image]

Although this graph does display what I want it to display (the data plotted against dates), I would like it to for example start by showing the first of the year (01/01/22) and then the end will be today's date (or the end of the year 12/31/22) and then with an interval of showing every month or every other month and not the dates that transactions are made.

Is there a way to do this by using the matplotlib? Or do I need to change my DataFrame to include every first of the month and the corresponding sales/cost/profit? Is there an easy way for me to do this?

I tried to do this:

> #plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y'))
> #plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=30))

Which gave me this graph which has the wrong dates on it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to fix it by adding the following lines of code:

> plt2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(plt2['Date'])

Which resulted in the dataframe handling the date column as an actual date.

Then for the graph I added this code:

```
months = mdates.MonthLocator() 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(plt2['Date'], plt2['Total_Sales'], linewidth = 4)
ax.plot(plt2['Date'], plt2['Total_Cost'], linewidth = 4)
ax.plot(plt2['Date'], plt2['Profit'], linewidth = 4)
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
```

Which resulted in the following graph:
[image]

Which I will still need to style, but these additions to my code basically turned my date column into readable date code. And so by creating a figure, the graph displayed the dates nicely which solved my issue.